# Multiple JPanels on top of each other?

Tags: java, jpanel, jlayeredpane

So I'm trying to make this 2D game, with a character and an enemy. I have seperat JPanels for the background, the enemy and the movable character. I tried putting all of them in the same JFrame, on top of each other, but the enemy JPanel and the character JPanel are not on top of each other, but rather next to each other. I also tried LayeredPane but couldn't really get it to work.

This is the code for the JFrame, if necessary, I could provide the code for the other classes aswell (keying is the character, enemy is the enemy (duh) and Images is the background):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Display extends JFrame{
    public JPanel gp = (JPanel) getGlassPane();
    public Images i;
    public static Keying k;
    public Enemy en;

    public Display() {
        i = new Images();
        gp.setVisible(true);
        k = new Keying(this, i);
        i.loadImages();
        en = new Enemy(k);

        gp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,0,0));

        gp.add(k);
        this.add(i);
        gp.add(en);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to have game layers, you create one and only one drawing `JPanel` and draw the background, enemy, and character images in succession.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: *"I have seperat JPanels for the background, the enemy and the movable character"* - I'd discourage you from doing this, as Swing component's are not well suited to task - instead, I'd encourage a workflow based on custom painting

Comment: *but the enemy JPanel and the character JPanel are not on top of each other,* - Swing has a parent/child relationship. I'm not sure how both panels can be on top of each other. Only one can be on top of the other. So if you want the "character" on top of the "enemy" then you need logic like: enemy.add(character). *gp = (JPanel) getGlassPane();* - don't attempt to use the glass pane like this. Generally you only  add Swing components to the content pane. However, as suggested above you really should be doing custom painting on a single JPanel for a game like this.